# Creating html table filled with lists on ASP page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table

I have two lists:

```
List<string> userID = new List<string>();
List<string> dates = new List<string>();
```

Both of these will always have the same amount of elements (Example below):

```
userID = [   11    |   22    |   33    |   44    |   55    ]
dates =  [ 1/22/13 | 2/22/13 | 3/22/13 | 4/22/13 | 5/22/13 ]
```

What I would like to do is create an HTML table on an ASP page with two columns, filled in by the elements of the lists, with userID[0] being the first cell under the first column, and dates[0] being the first cell under the second column like so:

```
columnName | column2Name
---------------------------
    11     |   1/22/13
    22     |   2/22/13
```

Right now I have:

```
<table style="border:solid black 2px" width="100%">
<tr style="border-bottom:solid black 2px">
   <td align="left"><%= dateSelect %></td>
   <td align="right">Date of Report: <%= System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Where `dateSelect` is a string.

This displays a single row table, which works and is what I want at the top of the table. Below that should be the two columns with headers of my choosing, then the elements.

I'm just not sure how to go about it (haven't had much HTML experience). Should I make a `Repeater` which I've seen suggested in similar questions, and then add `header` and `item` templates? Or is there a simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design page:

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server"></asp:Table>
```

In the code behind:

```
for(int i = 0; i < itemsnumber; i++){
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
    TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();
    tc1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span>" + List1[i].ToString() + "</span>"));
    tc2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span>" + List2[i].ToString() + "</span>"));
    tr.Controls.Add(tc1);
    tr.Controls.Add(tc2);
    Table1.Controls.Add(tr);
}
```

Comment: This works, but how would I go about formatting the cells and displaying the cell borders? Would that go in the asp or the c# code?

Comment: @pfinferno *tc1.Attributes.Style.Add("padding", "5px");*
In your design page you may add *CssClass="yourClassName"* to your Table control

Comment: @pfinferno style to Tablerow -> *tr.Attributes.Style.Add("text-align", "center");*

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use repeaters you can loop and render content in a style more similar to mvc, classic asp etc as per the example below:

```
<table>
  <% foreach (var myItem in g) { %>
    <tr><td><%= myItem.title %></td></tr>
  <% } %>
</table>
```

source:
[How to loop through data in WebForms like in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732801/how-to-loop-through-data-in-webforms-like-in-mvc)

I would add that repeaters would be the more typical approach with webforms i.e. a more expected approach for any other developer looking at your code later.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'll look more into repeaters since other developers will relate to it better.